# How to minimize my application with the Windows+m keyboard shortcut?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a simple winforms application in VB.NET 2008.  I am using a form with a completely custom look, so there is no title bar, thus no minimize, maximize, and close buttons. I've created custom controls to replace those.

If I have my app running, and I click the 'Show Desktop' shortcut, all the programs minimize properly, including mine.  But, if I use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> shortcut, all the programs EXCEPT mine minimize.  It seems that the lack of the built-in minimize button on the form causes my app to ignore <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

How can I detect <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, especially if my app is not active, or how can I duplicate the functionality of the built-in Minimize button?

**EDIT:**

I've tried implementing the following code, with no success.

```
Const WM_SIZE As Integer = &H5
Const SIZE_MINIMIZED As Integer = &H1

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
  MyBase.WndProc(m)

  If m.Msg = WM_SIZE Then
     If m.WParam = SIZE_MINIMIZED Then
        //Minimize the form.
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
     End If

  End If
End Sub
```

This seems like the right approach (thanks to SLaks), but my app doesn't seem to be receiving any messages from <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.  Or, more likely, I'm not intercepting them properly.

**EDIT:**

I've checked out the messages that my app is receiving with Spy++ (thanks again SLaks) and it looks like the `WM_SIZE` message is **not** getting sent to my app.  I tried a regular winforms app with the standard title bar and buttons, and it receives the `WM_SIZE` message as expected when <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is pressed.  Somehow the lack of a title bar is preventing the `WM_SIZE` message from being received in my custom form's WndProc.

**EDIT:**

The more I dig into this, the more that I think there may not be a way around this behavior.  I've confirmed that if the form does not have a border, no `WM_SIZE` message is received.  The developer sitting next to me uses C++ in Qt, and the exact same behavior is exhibited:  No form/window border = no message to minimize when <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is pressed.
<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> does work to minimize everything, but I believe that is a duplicate of the Show Desktop button.

I'm coming to the conclusion that if a form has no border, Windows does not even generate a message, thus there is no way to intercept it.  I've noticed that Windows Media Player exhibits this same behavior.  When it is in skinned mode, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> does not minimize it.

Comment: On behalf of the internet - thank you for caring about this in your program.

Comment: Did you check what happens in Spy++?

Comment: Instead of a borderless form, handle owner painting of the NC (border) area to make it look the way you want, but still act as a complete window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Spy++ to check which Windows messages your app receives when Window+M is pressed, then check for that message in your form's `WndProc` and minimze the form.

It appears that Windows+M sends a [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646(VS.85).aspx) message with wParam set to `SIZE_MINIMIZED`.

Comment: @SLaks, Thanks for this info.  I've tried implementing, with no luck yet, (code included in my edit).  Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this forum http://www.windows-tech.info/3/e4b66d1b1b690888.php the solution is to override the CreateParams method of the form.

Comment: That forum post addresses a completely different issue.  Taskbar toggling has never been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem.
The solution I found, is to hide the application when it's minimized. So the icon is visible in the taskbar when the window is open, but not visible when the application is minimised.